# Android's FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever's getFrameAtTime() returns corrupted Bitmap

Tags: android, video, bitmap, ffmpeg, decode

I have code that retrieves frames from a video.
It works ok, but when it gets to the last frame of a video, it returns a Bitmap which has (width = 1 and height = 8), from a 9:16 video.

What are the possible reasons ?